# How to estimate the Kalman Filter with 'KFAS' R package, with an AR(1) transition equation?

Tags: r, kalman-filter

I am using 'KFAS' package from R to estimate a state-space model with the Kalman filter. My measurement and transition equations are:

y_t = Z_t * x_t + \eps_t (measurement)

x_t = T_t * x_{t-1} + R_t * \eta_t (transition),

with \eps_t ~ N(0,H_t) and \eta_t ~ N(0,Q_t).

So, I want to estimate the variances H_t and Q_t, but also T_t, the AR(1) coefficient. My code is as follows:

```
library(KFAS)

set.seed(100)

eps <- rt(200, 4, 1)
meas <- as.matrix((arima.sim(n=200, list(ar=0.6), innov = rnorm(200)*sqrt(0.5)) + eps), 
ncol=1)

Zt <- 1
Ht <- matrix(NA)
Tt <- matrix(NA)
Rt <- 1
Qt <- matrix(NA)

ss_model <- SSModel(meas ~ -1 + SSMcustom(Z = Zt, T = Tt, R = Rt, 
                                             Q = Qt), H = Ht)
fit <- fitSSM(ss_model, inits = c(0,0.6,0), method = 'L-BFGS-B')
```

But it returns: *"Error in is.SSModel(do.call(updatefn, args = c(list(inits, model), update_args)),: System matrices (excluding Z) contain NA or infinite values, covariance matrices contain values larger than 1e+07"*

The NA definitions for the variances works well, as documented in the package's paper. However, it seems this cannot be done for the AR coefficients. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Note that I am aware of the SSMarima function, which eases the definition of the transition equation as ARIMA models. Although I am able to estimate the AR(1) coef. and Q_t this way, I still cannot estimate the \eps_t variance (H_t). Moreover, I am migrating my Kalman filter codes from EViews to R, so I need to learn SSMcustom for other models that are more complicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing something in your example, as your error message comes from the function `fitSSM`. If you want to use `fitSSM` for estimating general state space models, you need to provide your own model updating function. The default behaviour can only handle NA's in covariance matrices H and Q. The main goal of `fitSSM` is just to get started with simple stuff. For complex models and/or large data, I would recommend using your self-written objective function (with help of `logLik` method) and your favourite numerical optimization routines manually for maximum performance. Something like this:

```
library(KFAS)

set.seed(100)

eps <- rt(200, 4, 1)
meas <- as.matrix((arima.sim(n=200, list(ar=0.6), innov = rnorm(200)*sqrt(0.5)) + eps), 
ncol=1)

Zt <- 1
Ht <- matrix(NA)
Tt <- matrix(NA)
Rt <- 1
Qt <- matrix(NA)

ss_model <- SSModel(meas ~ -1 + SSMcustom(Z = Zt, T = Tt, R = Rt, 
                                             Q = Qt), H = Ht)

objf <- function(pars, model, estimate = TRUE) {
  model$H[1] <- pars[1]
  model$T[1] <- pars[2]
  model$Q[1] <- pars[3]
  if (estimate) {
  -logLik(model)
  } else {
    model
  }
}

opt <- optim(c(1, 0.5, 1), objf, method = "L-BFGS-B", 
  lower = c(0, -0.99, 0), upper = c(100, 0.99, 100), model = ss_model)

ss_model_opt <- objf(opt$par, ss_model, estimate = FALSE)
```

Same with `fitSSM`:

```
updatefn <- function(pars, model) {
  model$H[1] <- pars[1]
  model$T[1] <- pars[2]
  model$Q[1] <- pars[3]
  model
}


fit <- fitSSM(ss_model, c(1, 0.5, 1), updatefn, method = "L-BFGS-B", 
  lower = c(0, -0.99, 0), upper = c(100, 0.99, 100))

identical(ss_model_opt, fit$model)
```

Comment: You're right. I had forgotten the last line of code in my question (already edited). Anyway, your answer worked perfectly! Many thanks.